# Register dependency property on button

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I created a new class : ButtonLogin that extends Button class. I attached a new property called Immage. I created a style for it, but I have this error: **Error    11  Cannot find the static member 'ImmageProperty' on the type 'ButtonLogin'**

```
class ButtonLogin: Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Immage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ButtonLogin), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((ImageSource)null));


    public ImageSource Immage
    {
        get
        {
            return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonLogin" TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonLogin}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ButtonLogin}">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse>
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                           <ImageBrush ImageSource="/LogIq;component/Images/circ.fw.png"/>
                  </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Image Margin="21,17,19,18" Source="{TemplateBinding Immage}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I guess the problem is here: Source="{TemplateBinding Immage} , but I don't understand why, because I made another button the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DependencyProperty identifier name is incorrect**.

It should be `ImmageProperty` instead of `ImageProperty`.

Wrapper CLR properties and static DP identifier name should always be in sync because XAML internally uses DP identifier and not CLR wrapper properties.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, you have called your property `Immage` and your dependency property is `ImageProperty`. Rename the latter to `ImmageProperty`.